# Four equations and four unknown variables in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, physics

I'm trying to solve a problem in Mathematica where I have 4 unknown variables and 4 equations, but it doesn't quite work for me. I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
vdot = 20;
Temp = 10;
ρ = QuantityMagnitude[
   ThermodynamicData["Water", 
    "Density", {"Temperature" -> Quantity[Temp, "DegreesCelsius"]}]];
μ = QuantityMagnitude[
   ThermodynamicData["Water", 
    "Viscosity", {"Temperature" -> Quantity[Temp, "DegreesCelsius"]}]];
ϵ = 2*10^-6;
g = 9.81;
Le = 200;
eq1 = Reyn == (ρ v Diam)/μ;
eq2 = 1/Sqrt[
   f] == -2.0 Log10[(ϵ/Diam)/3.7 + 2.51/(Reyn Sqrt[f] )];
eq3 = 17 == f Le/Diam v^2/(2 g);
eq4 = v == vdot/((Diam/2)^2 π);
Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4}, {Reyn, v, f, Diam}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works

```
sol = FindRoot[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4}, {{Reyn, 10^7}, {v, 1}, {f, 1}, {Diam, 10}}]
```

> `{Reyn -> 1.55996*10^7, v -> 16.3066, f -> 0.00783754, Diam -> 1.24965}`

```
{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4} /. sol
```

> `{True, True, True, True}`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to act as follows. First, let us leave your parameters of the equation to stay symbols and solve the first, third and fourth equations:

```
eq1 = Reyn == (\[Rho] v Diam)/\[Mu]
eq2 = 1/Sqrt[f] == -2.0 Log10[(\[Epsilon]/Diam)/3.7 + 2.51/(Reyn Sqrt[f])]
eq3 = 17 == f Le/Diam v^2/(2 g)
eq4 = v == vdot/((Diam/2)^2 \[Pi])

sl = Solve[{eq1, eq3, eq4}, {Reyn, v, Diam}]
```

I guess you only need the solution in real values. The third of the solutions seems to be like this:

```
sl[[3]]

(* {Reyn -> (2 2^(2/5) 17^(1/5) g^(1/5) vdot^(3/5) ρ)/(
  f^(1/5) Le^(1/5) π^(3/5) μ), 
 v -> (2^(4/5) 17^(2/5) g^(2/5) vdot^(1/5))/(
  f^(2/5) Le^(2/5) π^(1/5)), 
 Diam -> (2^(3/5) f^(1/5) Le^(1/5) vdot^(2/5))/(
  17^(1/5) g^(1/5) π^(2/5))}  *)
```

Let us substitute it into eq2, and after that let us substitute your numbers instead of the symbols. For the latter aim let us first prepare a rule:

```
rule = {vdot -> 20, Temp -> 10, ρ ->QuantityMagnitude[
    ThermodynamicData["Water","Density", {"Temperature" ->Quantity[Temp, "DegreesCelsius"]}]], μ ->QuantityMagnitude[ThermodynamicData["Water", 
     "Viscosity", {"Temperature" ->Quantity[Temp, "DegreesCelsius"]}]],ϵ -> 2*10^-6,g -> 9.81, Le -> 200}
```

Now let us substitute:

```
eq2New = eq2 /. sl[[3]] /. rule

(*  1/Sqrt[f] == -0.868589 Log[
   4.24351*10^-7/f^(3/10) + 1.64012*10^-7/f^(1/5)]  *)
```

Now it becomes clear, why Mma does not return you any solution. Such transcendental equations are typically not solved with the function `Solve`. It can, however, be solved numerically. 
Let us first draw the parts of the equation:

```
[![Plot\[{-0.869 Log\[4.2435*^-7/f^(3/10) + 1.64`*^-7/f^(1/5)\], 1/Sqrt\[
  f\]}, {f, 0, 0.02}\]][1]][1]
```

we see that there is the cross-section somewhere below 0.01. Now we can safely solve it:

```
FindRoot[eq2New, {f, 0.05}]

(*  {f -> 0.00783754}  *)
```

Done. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) is an exact solver; use exact values:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
vdot = 20;
Temp = 10;

ρ = QuantityMagnitude[
    ThermodynamicData["Water", 
     "Density", {"Temperature" -> Quantity[Temp, "DegreesCelsius"]}]] // 
   Rationalize[#, 0] &;

μ = QuantityMagnitude[
    ThermodynamicData["Water", 
     "Viscosity", {"Temperature" -> Quantity[Temp, "DegreesCelsius"]}]] // 
   Rationalize[#, 0] &;

ϵ = 2*10^-6;
g = 981/100;
Le = 200;
eq1 = Reyn == (ρ v Diam)/μ;
eq2 = 1/Sqrt[
     f] == -2 Log10[(10 ϵ/Diam)/37 + 251/(100 Reyn Sqrt[f])];
eq3 = 17 == f Le/Diam v^2/(2 g);
eq4 = v == vdot/((Diam/2)^2 π);
```

Include the constraints that all variables are positive

```
sol = Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, Reyn > 0, v > 0, f > 0, Diam > 0}, 
 {Reyn, v, f, Diam}];
```

Verifying the solution

```
{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, Reyn > 0, v > 0, f > 0, Diam > 0} /. sol // 
 FullSimplify

(* {{True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}} *)
```

The approximate numeric values are

```
sol[[1]] // N

(* {Reyn -> 1.55996*10^7, v -> 16.3066, f -> 0.00783754, Diam -> 1.24965} *)
```